# PHP include attack

Tags: php

I can understand exactly what the `open_basedir ini` setting does but when reading the documentation it describes how it protects against include attacks - whereby an attacker can include files to attack the system.

I cant however find an example of this and exactly what this is.

Can an example be provided of such an attack

Comment: It needs to be combined with other bad code to really be exploited.  "Failing to specify a restrictive set of directories with open_basedir can make it easier for attackers to exploit other vulnerabilities."  Ref: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5

Answer (score 0):

You can include files of other users on the server.

so your filebase:
/home/marty/

Another users filebase:
/home/user231

Without open_basedir (and with wrong filepermissions), you can include an other users file:

```
include("/home/user231/public_html/connection.php");
```

Or:

```
file_get_contents("/home/user231/public_html/connection.php");
```

Comment: Yes. Correct... But it also makes sure you cant write outside that folder, so a hacker cannot write to /var/tmp if that is not in the basedir. It makes it a little harder to get to other files on your server using php.